# cannot connect to mysql using mysqli in php script

Tags: php

I am new to php. I am trying to connect to `SQLEXPRESS` server using `mysqli` from php script. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername,"root","");

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
echo "Connected successfully";

?>
```

I get an error that the target machine actively refuses the connection. My server is listening connections on port 63083. When I enter the port number in $servername:

```
 $servername = "localhost:63083";
```

then the script does not respond and after a few minutes I get an error that MySQL server has gone away. I would really appreciate some help in this regard.

Thanks

Comment: Where is the database server located?  Is it on your computer?

Comment: try `$conn = new mysqli($servername,"root");`

Comment: I could be wrong but I think _SQLEXPRESS_ is MSSQL not MySQL. I think you'll need [this](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php) extension to work with the DB.

Comment: I think War10ck is correct, but also looking at the link below it looks like if you want to set the port in mysqli you need to use the port parameter to the connect method: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot connect to an SQLEXPRESS server using PHP's `mysqli`. SQLEXPRESS has its own method of connecting with PHP. `mysqli` is only for MySQL servers.

Reference: http://www.sitepoint.com/sql-server-php/